# What kind of tree is this, and is the white "powder" on some leaves mean it's diseased?

Tags: identification, trees, diseases, tree-care

I live in southern California and moved into a new house a few months ago which had this tree planted in front of the house.  When we moved in, it was basically bare, but over the past couple months it has grown a lot of leaves.  I think I remember it having some purple blooms when we originally saw the house last November.

In any case, I noticed that the leaves on a good number (maybe 10-20%?) of the branches are covered with a fine white powder.  If I shake the branch, it comes right off into the air.  It definitely doesn't seem "right" but I know very little about this.

Is the tree diseased in some way, and if so, what should I do?  Also, what kind of tree **is** this?  I am attaching some photos below.

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a powdery mildew. I would take photos of plant, and get identification using this site or PlantID app. Then look up the plant in Westcott's Plant Disease Handbook for matching known diseases.